# Creating a Json output page with php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a json output but in converting some old code to mysqli I'm getting some errors.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");


$response = array();

$users = array();

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); //ERROR 1 points here

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //ERROR 2 points here
{ 
$firstname=$row['first_name']; 
$lastname=$row['last_name']; 

$users[] = array('firstname'=> $firstname, 'lastname'=> $lastname);

} 

$response['users'] = $users;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);


?>
```

I'm getting 2 errors: ...See comments in code above

1. Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in...
2. Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you already query the database here

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
```

So remove this line

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); //remove this line
```

And use `$sql` object to fetch data to avoid the second error

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
                             //^Change here from $result to $sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `mysqli_query` an object instead of a string:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); //ERROR 1 points here
```

From php [documentation][1]

```
Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries 
mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries 
mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
```

The second error is a consequence of the first, you should give $sql to the `mysqli_fetch_array` function.
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: Op is actually using `mysqli` and not `mysql`

Comment: Right, I misspelled the `mysqli_fetch_array` function.